# Calculate Cumulative Component Dependency and Average Component Dependency

Tags: component

Given is the following dependency graph of a system with two subsystems.
Calculate the CD (Component Dependency) of all components and also calculate the CCD and the ACD.
See CDD here https://structure101.com/2014/03/10/why-cyclic-dependencies-explode-complexity/

This is my calculation:

[image]

```
CCD = 5 + 2 + 2 + 2 + 8 + 1 + 1 = 21
ACC = CCD / number of elements = 21 / 7 = 3
```

Now my question, I have calculated the CCD and ACD. However, I do not know if my result is correct. Is this correct?

Comment: Didn't you ask this question a few days ago?

Comment: Yes, but since the question needed more 'details' (for whatever reason) it was removed and I was forced to ask it again of course improved

Answer (score 0):

You've got a small mistake but it ruined the calculation, instead of 8 the number should be 7 as there are only 7 entities in total.

Therefore, the calculation would be as follows:

```
CCD = 5 + 2 + 2 + 2 + 7 + 1 + 1 = 20.
ACC = 20/7 = 2.857.
RACD = ACD / number of elements * 100 = 40.81%.
```